# Make pictures repeat using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to create animation using JavaScript.

The pictures should be repeated (loop), the problem is when the script reaches the final picture there is an empty space.

What I want is: pic1 > pic2 > pic3 > pic4 > pic5 > pic1 > ...

**The code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    img { 
        position: absolute; 
        center: 0px; 
        top: 0px; 
    }

    #img3 { z-index: 3; }
    #img2 { z-index: 2; }
    #img1 { z-index: 1; }
</style>

<img style="top: 0px; height: 199px;" src="img1.jpg" id="img1">
<img img2.jpg" id="img2"><img src="img3.jpg" id="img3">


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('img').first().fadeOut(2000, function suivante() {
            $(this).next('img').fadeOut(2000,suivante);
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I found is that I should use the function bis() but I don't know how!

Comment: you are making all the picture disappear, a better approach is to use `fadeIn` along with `fadeOut` to make them visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

kee this in script section

```
 var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "images/1.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "images/2.jpg"
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src = "images/3.jpg"
    var image4 = new Image()
    image4.src = "images/4.jpg"
    var image5 = new Image()
    image5.src = "images/5.jpg"
    var image6 = new Image()
    image6.src = "images/6.jpg"
    var image7 = new Image()
    image7.src = "images/7.jpg"



<img src="images/1.jpg" name="slide" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;height:100px;width:250px" />
                 <script>
        <!--
            //variable that will increment through the images
            var step = 1
            function slideit() {
                //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
                if (!document.images)
                    return
                document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
                if (step < 7)
                    step++
                else
                    step = 1
                //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
                setTimeout("slideit()", 2000)
            }
            slideit()
        //-->
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your doing is hiding all images by fading out but never making them visible again.Add the following code at the begining of the  function suivante():

```
if($(this).attr("id")==="img5"){

    $('img').attr("display","block");

}
```

Comment: just the last image appear and then disappear